# laravel 4 API google maps integrate

Tags: google-maps, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel and am learning Laravel *4*. I have no idea how to integrate with the Google API... can someone please point me in the right direction? thank you very much

Comment: Which Google API do you want to use?  There are quite a few, and google's documentation is excellent in general.

Comment: You have lot of options, however, I prefer you to use googlMapper that provide you a lot of freedom to work. Know more-
http://www.tisuchi.com/add-google-map-laravel-googlmapper/

Answer (score 0):

Needed, I searched on Google and landed here but had no answer ..

I'm using this package: https://packagist.org/packages/toin0u/geotools-laravel

It is a wrapper of [GeoTools](https://github.com/thephpleague/geotools) (ThePHPLeague)

I used also: https://packagist.org/packages/egeloen/google-map